# NoClassDefFoundError on Espresso Tests

Tags: java, android, log4j, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

I was able to get robotium tests to work on our app but now I am having trouble with Espresso. I am getting "Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError":

```
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.log4j.lf5.viewer.categoryexplorer.CategoryNodeRenderer
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:305)
        at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfoSource.createPackageInfo(ClassPathPackageInfoSource.java:88)
        at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfoSource.access$000(ClassPathPackageInfoSource.java:39)
        at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfoSource$1.load(ClassPathPackageInfoSource.java:50)
        at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfoSource$1.load(ClassPathPackageInfoSource.java:47)
        at android.test.SimpleCache.get(SimpleCache.java:31)
        at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfoSource.getPackageInfo(ClassPathPackageInfoSource.java:72)
        at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfo.getSubpackages(ClassPathPackageInfo.java:48)
        at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfo.addTopLevelClassesTo(ClassPathPackageInfo.java:61)
        at android.test.ClassPathPackageInfo.getTopLevelClassesRecursive(ClassPathPackageInfo.java:55)
        at android.test.suitebuilder.TestGrouping.testCaseClassesInPackage(TestGrouping.java:156)
        at android.test.suitebuilder.TestGrouping.addPackagesRecursive(TestGrouping.java:117)
        at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.includePackages(TestSuiteBuilder.java:102)
        at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:366)
        at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner.java:114)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4319)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
```

Any help?
Here's my gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    androidTestCompile files('libs/espresso-contrib-1.1-bundled.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-logging-log4j-1.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/FiksuAndroidSDK_2.1.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile files('libs/internal.jar')
    compile files('libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar')
    compile files('libs/MobileAppTracker.jar')
    wearApp project(":wearable")
}
```

I'm using Android Studio and I don't have a separate Test Project. I think it has something to do with the "compile files('libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar')" and "androidTestCompile files('libs/espresso-contrib-1.1-bundled.jar')" being at odds with each other but not sure how to get around it. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was a conflicting library, log4j.

Removed this line and the corresponding .jar file and all was well.

```
compile files('libs/android-logging-log4j-1.0.3.jar')
```

Comment: I had a very similar problem where removing logback was the solution.